# Mat Snackbar not showing properly while calling inside file reader in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

Snackbar not showing in the top center, showing right side. After clicking on-screen anywhere then it shows correctly.

```
saveDoc(){
......
 var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onloadend = () => {
                var encodedData = reader.result;
                this._service.saveDoc(url, encodedData).subscribe((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this. showSnackBar('Annotation Saved', 2000)
                });
}

 showSnackBar(message: string): void {
        this._matSnackBar.open(message, 'OK', {
            verticalPosition: 'top',
            duration: 2000,
        });
    }
```

same issue happening if I use MatDialog as well, showing dialog properly, am closing that dialog automatically in 3 seconds using setTimeout
but it is not closing. If I click on screen it's closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of unrelated things:

- I would recommend using `const` instead of `var`;
- `this.showSnackBar` accepts 1 arg, but you are passing 2;

To fix your issue, you can try using [`ngZone`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#ngzone):

```
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    const encodedData = reader.result;
    this._service.saveDoc(url, encodedData).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this._ngZone.run(() => {
        this.showSnackBar('Annotation Saved');
      })
    });
  }
```

In your constructor:

```
constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```